# Prompt to enter (custom) document property in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, automation, ms-office

I created a template with a custom document property called "myproperty". I can access this using fields with the DOCPROPERTY "myproperty" command.
I want to make Word prompt the user for a value and set it as a value for myproperty. I know I can prompt using the FILLIN command, but I don't know how to pass the value to myproperty. The SET command seems to work only with bookmarks.

Any ideas how to achieve this? I suppose it might be possible using Visual Basic too.

Regards,
naroslife

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for user input in the document to update a document property the Custom Document Property must be created using VBA and linked to a bookmark. This change will not show up, however, until the document has been saved, closed and re-opened. I suspect this is not optimal behavior for your purposes...

So your only option would be to use code, such as VBA. A very simple approach would be to display an InputBox then write the result to the property. For this to be really robust, you'd probably also need to validate the user input.

StackOverflow is not a free code source or teaching site, so I'm just going to show you the bare bones of this. You'll need to do some research if you want to extend the code with validation.

```
Sub GetDocPropVal()
    Dim sInput As String

    sInput = InputBox("Enter the property value", "Getting my doc prop val", "default val")
    ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Test").value = sInput
End Sub
```

Comment: That is certainly a good starting ground, thank you! I managed to make what I wanted.